# TinyMce with Knock out binding

Tags: tinymce

I am using [Michaelpapworth](https://github.com/michaelpapworth/tinymce-knockout-binding) knockout+ tinymce binding , which is very helpful, thanx to him for creating it. I could create Tinymce editor, and bind it. The problem i am not getting the text value to my observable until unless i change design of text like making it bold, em , strong etc.

Updates are not reflecting in knockout observable in instance.

My plugin versions are:

- tinymce.min.js( 4.0.28 (2014-05-27))
- tinymce-knockout-binding v1.1.0|(c)
- tinymce_4.0.28
- knock out 3.1.0

Design:

```
        <div id="event_container">

      <table class="form" data-bind="with:EventModel">

        <td>
                <textarea data-bind="wysiwyg: EventDesc " rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: EventDesc" />
       </td>
        |
        |
      </table>
      </div>
```

Viewmodel vm:

```
        self.EventDesc = ko.observable();

          |
          |
          |
         ko.bindingHandlers['wysiwyg'].defaults = {
        'plugins': ['link'],
        'toolbar': 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist | link',
        'menubar': false,
        'statusbar': false
    };

       ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("event_container"));
```